# Text appear after Splash screen

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-studio

I want the Layout"authentification" to appear after the Splash screen, in my application it's appear by default please some one help me!!!!!
pleaaase i need help

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
        LinearLayout ln;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splashh);

    ln = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinLaySpalScrenLogin);



            final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            final Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.rotate);
            final Animation an2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.abc_fade_out);

            iv.startAnimation(an);
            an.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    iv.startAnimation(an2);
                    finish();

    ln.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean?? you are not able get the splash screen first?

Comment: why do you finish current activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `android:visibility="gone"` in your LinearLayout xml file that contains your Splash Screen and then call `yourlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` after you finish your animation.
Also your activity will end as soon as your animation finishes since you have called `finish()` before `ln.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` Try to remove `finish()` and only call it on some event such as Button click or something like that

Comment: Thanx a lot :) _Aamir_

Answer (score 0):

You have `ln.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` after `finish();`. Try changing to :-

```
    ln.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    finish();
```

However, this will probably not work as because as soon as the make the layout visible. The activity would finish. You probably want to display the authentication in another activity after the splash has completed.